# Ionic 2 update checked items in checkbox alert

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2

I am having an issue with my Ionic 2 checkbox alert. I am not able to get it to update what has been checked when it is reopened. I do understand that the one that Ionic has in their docs works just fine. However, I do not want to list the items that were checked in the small area to the right of the label. I want to list the checked items below it. I am able to update this list with what is currently checked but the alert will not reflect the change. I apologize if this question has already been asked. I have searched and not found a solution to my particular problem. Thank for any help.

Typescript file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public activitiesList: any;
  public selectedActivities: Array<string>

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    this.activitiesList = [
      { name: 'Biking', checked: false },
      { name: 'Hiking', checked: false },
      { name: 'Lifting', checked: false },
      { name: 'Sleeping', checked: false }
    ];
    this.selectedActivities = [];
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() { }

  selectPreferredActivities() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create();
    alert.setTitle('Preferred Activities');
    for (let activity of this.activitiesList) {
      alert.addInput({
        type: 'checkbox',
        label: activity.name,
        value: activity.name,
        checked: activity.checked
      });
    }
    alert.addButton('Cancel');
    alert.addButton({
      text: 'Ok',
      handler: selected => {
        this.selectedActivities = selected;
        this.updateActivitiesList(this.selectedActivities);
      }
    });
    alert.present();
  }

  updateActivitiesList(selectedActivities) {
    let selectedActivity;
    for (selectedActivity of selectedActivities) {
      for (let activity = 0; activity < this.activitiesList.length; activity++) {
        if (selectedActivity === this.activitiesList[activity].name) {
          this.activitiesList[activity].checked = true;
        } else {
          this.activitiesList[activity].checked = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Html file:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  The world is your oyster.
  <p>
    If you get lost, the <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">docs</a> will be your guide.
  </p>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-divider>
      <button ion-button (click)="selectPreferredActivities()">Button</button>
    </ion-item-divider>
    <ion-list no-lines>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let item of selectedActivities">
        {{item}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```